# Rules Workflow: Data selector is invalid

Tags: 7, rules, workflows

A website that has a workflow system based on Rules, as detailed [here](http://drupal.org/node/1027546)

Some of the rules use the condition '**User has role(s)**', and all these rules now show the following error:

> Error: Data selector site:current-user for parameter account is invalid.

The condition must have been valid when it was created, or the rule would not have been saved.

The site uses **Entity API 7.x-1.0-rc3** and **Rules 7.x-2.2**.

Any suggestions? Even deleting and recreating the rule does not work, as I cannot seem to find site-current-user in the Data Selector dropdown.

Comment: try clearing your cache once

Comment: I have already tried this. It doesn't help.

Comment: well..if possible try reinstalling the modules but i guess it will hamper your other work...let me check

Comment: Try upgrading entity to latest version.

Comment: Entity and Rules are already at the latest recommended versions. Company policy forbids me from installing the development releases.

Comment: Posting the rule export file may help us help you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the UUID module. Updating it to the latest version fixed this issue.

Similar problem at: [Enabling UUID breaks rules config set by Ubercart](http://drupal.org/node/1788350).

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> Data selector %selector for parameter %name is invalid.

usually happens when specific parameter is not available at given time.

This is the condition which throws the error (`rules.core.inc`):

```
// ...
elseif (!empty($this->settings[$name . ':select']) && !$this->applyDataSelector($this->settings[$name . ':select'])) {
  throw new RulesIntegrityException(t("Data selector %selector for parameter %name is invalid.", array('%selector' => $this->settings[$name . ':select'], '%name' => $name)), array($this, 'parameter', $name));
}
```

and usually it happens, because the parent token is not listed in `$this->availableVariables()` as per code below:

```
public function applyDataSelector($selector) {
  $parts = explode(':', str_replace('-', '_', $selector), 2);
  if (($vars = $this->availableVariables()) && isset($vars[$parts[0]]['type'])) {
    $wrapper = rules_wrap_data(NULL, $vars[$parts[0]], TRUE);
    // ...
```